# Python 2.7 Trying to make a NOT truth table where 0 becomes 1 and vice versa in the output

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
>>> print not(0, 0, 0, 0)
False
```

...keeps returning `False` but my output should be `(1, 1, 1, 1)`, what am I doing wrong here?

When I made the truth tables for AND and OR they worked as I wanted them to:

```
>>> print (0 and 0 and 0 and 0)
0
>>> print (0 or 0 or 0 or 0)
0
```

Answer (score 1):

Any object has a truth value, which in case of a non-empty tuple is `True`. So you are supplying the `not` keyword with the `(0, 0, 0, 0)` tuple instance. What `not` does is simply inverts the boolean value supplied to it.

As `bool((0, 0, 0, 0,)) == True` the value of `not (0, 0, 0, 0) == False`.

What you need though is the following:

```
[int(not bit) for bit in data]
```

This will take each bit in your data, and invert it's boolean value. Then the `int` part will turn the boolean into an integer `0` or `1`.

Comment: Thank you very much kind sir! this answered my question and now my truth table is working the way I want it to!

Answer (score 1):

This is because the boolean value of a tuple with more than one item in it is always `True`:

```
>>> bool((0,0))
True
>>> bool((0,0,0))
True
```

When you evaluate the boolean value of a list or tuple, it doesn't check the boolean value of every single item individually.

Instead, you can try the following:

```
>>> all((not(i) for i in (0,0,0,0)))
True
```

This evaluates the boolean value individually using a generator expression, and uses `all` to make sure every value is `True`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the Python keywords `all` and `any` for such task.
You can think of `all` as equivalent to `AND` and `any` as equivalent to `OR`. For more details refer this [page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html)

In your case, you could run the command

```
all((0, 0, 0, 0))
```

and it does indeed return `False` as you expect.